# D/skia: libjpeg error 117 <Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data

Tags: java, android, bitmap, decode

I am not gating error but when i clicked recyclerview->image view

```
    D/skia: libjpeg error 117 <Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment> from output_message
D/skia: ------ png error IEJ[84]: invalid chunk type
        png onGetPixels Handle incomplete interlaced pngs L481
        --- codec->getAndroidPixels() failed.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

In Recycler View Adapter OnImage Click I am Doing Like This

```
text3DonImageActivity.text3DonImageContainer.setMainImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(MaskImageValue.DecodedMainImagesString.get(i), 0, MaskImageValue.DecodedMainImagesString.get(i).length));

text3DonImageActivity.text3DonImageContainer.setMaskImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(MaskImageValue.DecodedMaskImagesString.get(i), 0, MaskImageValue.DecodedMaskImagesString.get(i).length));
```

in The setMain And mask Image

```
public static void setMainImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mainImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public static void setMaskImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    maskImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    maskImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

> Prob:

When I clicked Image Main Image Set Successfully 
but Mask Image not set

No Error Showed only This Log was Appears in Log window....

```
D/skia: libjpeg error 117 <Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment> from output_message
```

D/skia: ------ png error IEJ[84]: invalid chunk type
        png onGetPixels Handle incomplete interlaced pngs L481
        --- codec->getAndroidPixels() failed.
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

I am so Confused any One help me..

Thanks In Advance......

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it seems the problem was with the data type I was using. I was using **blob** in my maria db database but once I changed it to **LONGBLOB**, it worked perfectly